# Functions to receive valid integer within parameters

Tags: c, function

I've been writing two functions, the first receives a valid integer from the user and outputs and error message if the integer is followed up by say a character. Aside from outputting the error message for every invalid character, the function was working as intended. However, with my second function, I am trying to have the integer from the first function check itself against the parameters of the second function, but I am met with a segmentation fault, so I'm unsure as to where I went wrong. The second function should essentially only allow the user to proceed if the integer entered is within what should be the max and min limits, although these limits are not specified at this point in time.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>      

int main(void){
    int iVal;
    double dVal;
    welcome();
    printTitle();
    double grandtotal = 1234.57;
    printFooter(grandtotal);
    flushKeyboard();
    pause();
    getInt();
    getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit);

    return 0;
}


 void flushKeyboard(void)
{
    int read;

    while (( read = getchar()) != '\n')
    return;
}

void pause(void)
{
    printf("Press <ENTER> to continue...\n");
    flushKeyboard();
    return;
}



int getInt(void)
{
    int validInt;
    char NL = 'x';

    while (NL != '\n') {
            scanf("%d%c", &validInt, &NL);

    if (NL != '\n') {
            flushKeyboard();
            printf("Invalid integer, please try again: \n");
        }
    }
    return validInt;
}

int getIntLimited(int lowerLimit, int upperLimit)
{
    int limit;
    do {

            limit = getInt();

            if(lowerLimit > limit || limit > upperLimit) {
                    printf("Invalid value, %d < %d < %d: ", lowerLimit, limit, upperLimit);
            }
    }

            while(lowerLimit < limit && limit < upperLimit);
    return limit;

}
```

Comment: `scanf("%d%c", validInt, NL)` gives undefined behaviour... you need to pass the addresses of the variables, not the values.  Also, you should check its return value to determine whether the fields were scanned and assigned.

Comment: + to what @Dmitri wrote, `scanf` scans the input buffer till `'\n'` or `' '`, so your `scanf` should be `scanf("%d", &validInt);` and if you want to check that the integer is valid you need to read the whole input as a string and then parse it and search for illegal characters (assume input like this: `12PP2<enter>`). When the check is completed the string should be converted to an integer.

Comment: the value input by `getchar()` also needs to be checked for EOF.  Therefore, the variable being set by the returned value from `getchar()` needs to be an `int`, not a `char`

Comment: The posted code is missing a LOT of items, like the definitions of several functions, the needed `#include` statements, etc.  The question references a run time problem, but the code does not compile and the actual inputs and expected and actual outputs are not posted.  So this question is off topic

Comment: I left out the other functions because I don't think they have any relation to the functions I am focused on. I have updated with Dmitri's suggestion, to use addresses instead of variables as well as user's suggestion to change char to int and the first function is working mostly fine now. I was dealing with a lot of printf statements and completely forgot to pass the addresses rather than the values for scanf. The only issue with the function getInt is that it outputs multiple error messages. Ex. If you enter 2das, you'll get 3 error messages instead of one.